# ggplot stat_density with facet_wrap and single stat_density doesn't match

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a df with 3 sector's wacc data. When I plot the density for one sector I get the real object. The energy sector wacc density plot:

[image: energy sector wacc density]

But when I use the facet_wrap the density function is totally wrong, because I get the following graph:

[image: density plot with facet wrap]

How do I get the real density plot when using facet_wrap?

Here is the code:

```
 wacc <- c(0.05,0.05,0.07,0.05,0.06,0.04,0.04,0.03,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.03,0.03,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.04,0.05,0.05,0.04,0.05,0.04,0.04,0.06,0.04,0.04,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.09,0.1,0.08,0.09,0.09,0.08,0.1,0.09,0.1,0.13,0.06,0.09,0.1,0.1,0.09,0.11,0.09,0.08,0.08,0.09,0.08,0.06,0.08,0.06,0.08,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.07,0.1,0.08)
sector <- c("Telecommunication Services","Telecommunication Services","Telecommunication Services","Telecommunication Services","Telecommunication Services","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Utilities","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy","Energy")
df <- data.frame(wacc, sector)
ggplot(df, aes(df$wacc))+stat_density()+facet_wrap(~sector)
```

Comment: the aes should be `aes(wacc)` not `aes(df$wacc)`. Does that fix your problem?

Comment: unbelievable, thanks, it's working

Comment: but why is it wrong when i use df$wacc?